# How to choose an optimal dimension reduction factor in LSA processing

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, natural-language, latent-semantic-analysis

I'm performing a K-Means clustering on a 400.000 text dataset. After eliminating useless chars and removing stopwords, I get a dictionnary size of around 42000 words. 
So before doing the clustering, I apply a LSA/TSIDF preprocessing to reduce dimensionality of my count matrix

My question is how do you choose an optimal dimension reduction factor? I've read on some paper that usually LSA allows a good dimensionality reduction by approx. 100-300. So basically, should I choose a new matrix with features dimension between 133-400 ?

Comment: What do you mean by "400.000 text dataset"? 400k tokens?

Comment: 400.000 text documents, each having a length of 2 to 3 regular pages (didn't count how many words).